# PKCS11Exception ckr_attribute_type_invalid

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, keystore, pkcs#11

I am trying to create a keystore to get a private key with a smart card reader.

```
String config = "name = AKIS\nlibrary = C:/Windows/System32/akisp11.dll";
Security.addProvider(akisProvider);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", akisProvider);
ks.load(null, "000000".toCharArray());
```

But it gives me this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: load failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:763)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at deneme.AkisImzaImpl.dene(AkisImzaImpl.java:55)
    at deneme.Deneme.main(Deneme.java:83)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetAttributeValue(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$SynchronizedPKCS11.C_GetAttributeValue(PKCS11.java:1623)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.mapLabels(P11KeyStore.java:2277)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:755)
    ... 3 more
```

This code was working until yesterday. I could not figure out the problem. If you can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow okorkut! Please take heed which tags you are using. Always indicate language / runtime (i.e. Java) and make sure you are using high level tags with lots of followers. One of your tags actually had *do not use* in the description!

Comment: It there anything changed in your environment? The PKCS#11 dll maybe? Or have you added objects to your token? Unfortunately the exception is terribly unhelpful with regard to the actual issue as `C_GetAttributeValue` may be called for any object in the token.

Comment: There haven't been any changes. I downloaded and installed and installed the driver from the website provides me the smartcard reader. I tried the example code to test that it works. It did work back than. But it is not working anymore.

Comment: API loggers like [this](https://github.com/jariq/pkcs11-logger) are extremely useful for looking "under the hood".

Comment: @vlp Ah, I didn't know that there was an open source one, good to know! Here is to hoping that the other .dll doesn't use any proprietary methods...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes (Theoretically) in case of proprietary methods it should be possible to _inject_ the logger using [dll injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection).

Comment: smart card has 2 certificates and 3 keys. One of the keys does not have a name or id while the other two has them. Could it be related to that.

Comment: @okorkut if you take a look at [Java PKCS#11 Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) you will see that `CKA_LABEL` and `CKA_ID` attributes play important role for SunPKCS11 provider. However in your question you have mentioned you are getting `CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID` error. Did the logs reveal which attribute of which object caused this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out. One of the 3 keys which does not have any ID was extra. I contacted the card company and we removed the extra key. Now it loads without a problem. Thanks for your help.